# Smoke simulation frozen

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am having a problem with my smoke simulation. I created an emitter and added the quick smoke preset.
But when I press play the simulation only shows the first frame.
When I do the same in a blank blender project, everything is working as expected.
Is there any Project setting that I might need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the file in your question? You can do this by going to blend-exchanges.com and adding the link in your question.